# Is it possible to animate BigDecimal using ValueAnimator?

Tags: android

I'm trying to show money with animation ($0.00 -> $999.999.999.999.00)

Is it possible to animate BigDecimal using ValueAnimator or something else?

I think since numbers that I'm dealing with are too big I couldn't use [`valueAnimator.ofFloat()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ValueAnimator.html#ofFloat(float...))

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you normalize the numbers? Like if you are wanting between $0.00 -> $X.XX, set your max value to be 1, then each step would be ($Y.YY)/($X.XX). This would give you a value from 0->1